# ¿Cómo insertar tres array en un pívot laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, array, eloquent, guardar

tardes o noches

Tengo un problema es que trato de insertar 3 arrays
bueno , se que se me envia los datos por "return request" [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo los modelos relacionado , les dejo para puedan verlos y ver si  están bien o como
mejorar
Bueno tengo 2 tablas que se relaciona a una pivot y en la pivot añado 1 dato extra que es "EstadoDeAsistencia"
Modelo Estudiante

protected $table = "estudiante";
use HasFactory;

```
// relacion de mucho a mucho a 

public function estudiantes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany
    (fecha_asistencia::class,
    'Estudiante_id', 'estudiante_fecha  ', 'fecha_asistencia_id');
}
```

este es el modelo FECHA solo guarda la fecha por si acaso "se que el nombre esta mal implementado lo siento"

```
class Fecha_Asistencia extends Model
```

{
protected $table = "fecha";

```
use HasFactory;



public function estudiantes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(fecha_asistencia::class
    , 'estudiante_fecha', 'Estudiante_id ', 'fecha_asistencia_id');
}
```

}

Y POR ultimo la modelo pivot

```
 protected $table = "estudiante_fecha";
use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = [
    'Estudiante_id',
    'fecha_asistencia_id',
    'EstadoAsistencia'
];
```

ahora no se como guardar en el controlador e echo mucho intentos pero casi todo fallaron a si que no se como guardarlo , por favor ayudenme :c
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se olviden que quiero agregar 3 arrays en una tabla desde

a qui les dejo la vista

Comment: Ibas tan bien agregando el codigo como texto... y despues ya no... El codigo debe ir como texto, no todos pueden visualizar las imagenes...lee [ask]

Comment: Lo único que dejo como imagen es la vista ya que el controlador no tengo nada , es puro dato comentado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al fin pude encontrar como guardas mas de 3 arrays mandando desde el formulario a la tabla pivot , bueno para empezar mejore mis controladores y cree una tabla "parametriza dora"

Una vez creado la 2 tablas
Estudiante y tabla Fecha , para guardar todo en Estudiante_fecha con sus claves foraneas

que daría algo como esto

Estudiante_fecha

Estudiante_id
Fecha_id

en mis modelos esta a si en modelo estudiante

```
public function estudiantes_fechas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Estudiante_Fecha::class);
}
```

seguimos ahora con el modelo FECHA

```
protected $table = "fecha_asistencia";
use HasFactory;
public function estudiantes_fechas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Estudiante_Fecha::class);
}
```

Bueno y ahora por ultimo si el pivot que es Estudiante_Fecha

```
protected $table = "estudiante_fecha";

protected $fillable = [
    'Estudiante_id',
    'fecha_asistencia_id',
    'estado_id'
]; 
//es para mostrar los datos de llave foranea
public function estudiantes(){
return $this->belongsTo(Estudiante::class,'Estudiante_id','id');
}
// esta es la relacion de FECHAS
public function Fechas(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Fecha_Asistencia::class,'fecha_asistencia_id','id');
}
```

y cree un modelo de ESTADO , es solo para guardar asistencia y no tiene relación con nada , lo dejare por a qui si es que existe gente que se pregunta que hacer con tabla parametriza dora

```
class estado extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $table = "estado";
}
```

Luego en la funcio CREATE de mi controllador DocenteController mando por compact los datos que quiero que se almacene en mi pivot

```
public function create()
{
    $estudiante= Estudiante::all();
    $Fecha= Fecha::all();
    $estado=estado::all();
    return view('docente.create',
    compact('estudiante','Fecha','estado'));     
}
```

Luego demandar todo esto a la vista , creo el formulario con los datos

```
 <form action="{{route('docente.store')}}" method="post">
  @csrf
  
  @foreach($estudiante as $dato)
  <tr>
    <td>
      {{$dato -> id}}
    </td>
    <td>
    <select class="form-select form-select-sm" disabled name="Estudiante_id[]">
    <option
      class="form-control" value="{{$dato->id}}">
      {{$dato -> NombreEstudiante}}
    </option>
  </select>
    </td>
  {{-- {{$dato -> fecha}} --}}
    @foreach($FechaAsistencias as $datofecha)
    <td>
      
   <select class="form-select form-select-sm" disabled
   name="fecha_asistencia_id[]">
    <option
      class="form-control" value="{{$datofecha ->id}}">
      {{$datofecha -> fecha}}
    </option>
  </select>
  
    
    </td>
    @endforeach



    <td>
      <select class="form-select form-select-sm" 
       name="estado_id[]">
        @foreach($estado as $datos1)
        <option value="{{$datos1 -> id}}">{{$datos1 -> estado}} 
      </option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </td>
    @endforeach
    </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline- 
    primary">SUBIR 
    ASISTENCIA</button>
    </form>
    @endsection
```

Luego almaceno por fin con un FOR intente usar un FORECH pero dublicaba los datos

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  //guarda la asistencia 
for($i = 0; $i <= count($request->all()) ; $i++) {
    Estudiante_Fecha::create([
        'Estudiante_id' =>$request->Estudiante_id[$i],
        'fecha_id'=>$request- >fecha_id[$i],
        'estado_id' => $request->estado_id[$i]
         ]);
          }
       }
```